# Incorrect Read Receipt generated by default mail app on Android 4

Tags: email, bugs

The default mail app on Android 4 seems to generate incorrect Read Receipts. 
Here is the case:

User ORIGINATOR sends email (using any mail client software), with request for Read Receipt (SMTP header Disposition-Notification-To), TO: PRIMARY-RECEIVER with CC: SECONDARY-RECEIVER.

When PRIMARY-RECEIVER opens the email, his email client will (optionally) send a Read Receipt which is FROM: PRIMARY-RECEIVER TO: ORIGINATOR.

When SECONDARY-RECEIVER opens the email, his email client should (optionally) send a Read Receipt which is FROM: SECONDARY-RECEIVER TO: ORIGINATOR.

But if SECONDARY-RECEIVER opens the email on Android 4 (Galaxy S3 in my tests), using the default email client, the phone sends a Read Receipt which is FROM: PRIMARY-RECEIVER TO: ORIGINATOR, which is grossly incorrect.

Has anyone detected the same issue?

Anyone has a suggestion on proper forum or support channel for reporting this bug?